# libGD error "no PNG support" when compiling example

Tags: c

Don't know how to tell the compiler to find PNG.

The example "arc.c" is from libgd-2.2.5/examples directory. I installed gd-devel: # yum install gd-devel. I even did try to install libgd-2.2.5 with ./configure, make, make install; which was installed in "/usr/local". And still, I get this error: "no PNG support" when compiling "arc.c" like this:

```
[none@localhost ~]$ gcc arc.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/include -lgd

[none@localhost ~]$ ls

a.out arc.c arc.o

[none@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

no PNG support
```

content of /usr/local/lib: << libgd.a  libgd.la  libgd.so  libgd.so.3  libgd.so.3.0.5 >>

also, checking if there is PNG support, with:

```
[none@localhost ~]$ ldconfig -p | grep libpng

libpng16.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpng16.so.16
```

which says "PNG support" is installed.

arc.c

```
01  #include "gd.h"
02  #include <stdio.h>
03  #include <stdlib.h>
04
05  int main()
06  {
07      gdImagePtr im;
08      FILE *fp;
09      int cor_rad = 60;
10      im = gdImageCreateTrueColor(400, 400);
11      gdImageFilledRectangle(im, 0, 0, 399, 399, 0x00FFFFFF);
12
13      gdImageFilledArc (im, cor_rad, 399 - cor_rad, cor_rad *2, cor_rad *2, 90, 180, 0x0, gdPie);
14
15      fp = fopen("b.png", "wb");
16      if (!fp) {
17          fprintf(stderr, "Can't save png image.\n");
18          gdImageDestroy(im);
19          return 1;
20      }
21  #ifdef HAVE_LIBPNG
22      gdImagePng(im, fp);
23  #else
24      printf("No PNG support. Cannot save image.\n");  
25  #endif
26      fclose(fp);
27
28      gdImageDestroy(im);
29      return 0;
30  }
```

Clearly, the error comes from line: 21 and 24. Where "#ifdef HAVE_LIBPNG" is verified?

How do I tell the compiler to find PNG support?

Comment: LibGDX is a Java-based game engine. I think you have the wrong tag.

Comment: Oh..I see. thank you. I saw something was wrong when posted. It would not give me libgd tag without 'x'.

Comment: I would tag it with the language(s) you're using at least, so it will get more attention.